# chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags

Tags: permissions

I want to move a file from my Raspberry Pi (Openhabian OS) to a USB stick, however  the `cp` command returns `cp dir1/Controller.py /media/usb/
cp: cannot create regular file '/media/usb/Controller.py': Permission denied`.

I tried to get permission via chown and chmod:

```
chmod 777 /media/usb/
sudo chown openhabian:openhabian /media/usb/
```

These two went through without an issue, however the problem remains.

The attribute change I tried using

```
sudo chattr -i /media/usb/
```

returned the error:

```
chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on /media/usb/
```

How can I get the permissions I need to write on /media/usb/ ?

**EDIT:**

The input

```
openhabian@openHABianPi:~$ ls -ld /media/usb/
```

returns

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 openhabian openhabian 4096 Nov 13 19:44 /media/usb/
```

and the input

```
openhabian@openHABianPi:~$ mount | grep media/usb
```

returns

```
/dev/sda1 on /media/usb type ntfs (rw,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0177,dmask=077,nls=utf8,errors=continue,mft_zone_multiplier=1)
```

Answer (score 8):

From the output, you can not change file attributes on ntfs.
`chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on /media/usb/` ;
`chattr` is only for Linux systems, aka, supported filesystems, like xfs,ext4, etc, but also, there are some minor limitations as well. You can not use it on `ntfs` based filesystem.

`man chattr`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was try to set immutable in a file, but the file was a symbolic link. Chattr not is to set flags in symbolic links.

I removed the symbolic link and recreate as file and then set immutable.